# java how to replace variables in a method

Tags: java, string, replace

I need to replace all occurrences with the name that is given by the user with the new name.
Here is my code:

```
public class Person
{
  public Person() {}

  public Person(String name, String address, String email, String phone)
  {
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  this.email = email;
  this.phone = phone;
  }

  String name = "";
  String address = "";
  String email = "";
  String phone = "";

  public String toString()
  {
  return "Name: " + name + "  Address: " + address + "  Email: " + email + "  Phone: " + phone;
  }
}


class Student extends Person
{
  public Student() {}

  public Student(String studentName, String studentAddress, String studentEmail, String studentPhone)
  {
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    this.studentEmail = studentEmail;
    this.studentPhone = studentPhone;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String studentInfo = super.toString();
    return studentInfo.replaceAll(name, studentName);
  }

  //int grade = 0;  COME BACK TO THIS
  String studentName = "";
  String studentAddress = "";
  String studentEmail = "";
  String studentPhone = "";
  public static final int freshman = 0;
  public static final int sophomore = 1;
  public static final int junior = 2;
  public static final int senior = 3;
}
```

Right now it replaces every letter with the name that the user passes.  How can I get it to only replace the actual name?

Comment: The `Student` class doesn't need a second set of variables for "studentName" etc. -- it can simply use the "name" variable in the Person class since it (Student) is a sub-class of Person. The `Student` constructor can just do `this.name = studentName` then Student doesn't even need to override `toString` because Person.toString already does exactly the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, that is a terrible idea.  Instead, I suggest something like this:

```
// In the student class.
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + studentName +
        "  Address: " + studentAddress +
        "  Email: " + studentEmail +
        "  Phone: " + studentPhone;
}
```

or this

```
// In the student class.
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + studentName +
        "  Address: " + address +
        "  Email: " + email +
        "  Phone: " + phone;
}
```

Comment: I want it to ovveride the person toString() method

Comment: indeed, that is why I named the method "toString".  Note the comment above the method name; "In the student class".

Comment: Why does "Student" even _have_ a "studentName" variable? It can just use "name" from the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Call `studentInfo.replace(name, studentName)` rather than `studentInfo.replaceAll(name, studentName)`.

Comment: I tried this and it just puts the newName first.  Then it prints all of the studentInfo.

Comment: This will replace the first occurrence of `name`, not necessarily the one he wants...